# Joining multiple one-to-many tables with Linq to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Well I am trying to join 3 tables here is a brief summary of them

**user** - id,name,.....

**contactdetails** - id,detail,....,*userId*

**adress** - id,adress,.......*contactdetailsId*

how do I join these 3 tables with linq to sql?

Answer (score 1):

Write something like (I can't read out the entire structure of the DB from your question):

```
var q = from a in ctx.address
select new {
    a.address,
    a.concactdetails.detail,
    a.contactdetils.user.name
};
```

When having one-to-many relationships it's easiest to base the query on the table which "is most many". It is possible to do it the other way around and use `LoadWith` options. Unfortunately linq-to-sql only supports translating two tables into efficient querys when done that way. If you try it with three tables you will get a load of small fetch-one-line-queries hitting the DB dragging performance down terribly (see http://coding.abel.nu/2011/11/always-check-generated-sql/ for an example).

Answer (score 0):

```
        ContactDetail[] ContactDetails = new ContactDetail[0]; // your contact detail entries
        Address[] Addresses = new Address[0]; // your address entries
        User[] Users = new User[0]; // your user entries
        Users.Join(ContactDetails, user => user.ID, cd => cd.ID, (user, cd) => new { User = user, ContactDetail = cd }).Join(Addresses, UserAndCD => UserAndCD.ContactDetail.ID, address=>address.ContactDetailID, (UserAndCD, address)=> new {User = UserAndCD.User, ContactDetail = UserAndCD.ContactDetail, Address = address});
```

In this case you will get user-contactdetail-address entries. If you want to get a user with contactdetail enumeration, and an address enumeration for each contactdetail, then you have to use GroupJoin: